# Understand variable place holder for curl command in Dockerfile

Tags: curl, docker

I am learning about Dockerfile and had not worked with curl before.

I am trying to understand line 26 in [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/popestepheng/meteor-production-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile) .

```
&& bash -c 'curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/$(<.node_version.txt)/node-$(<.node_version.txt)-linux-x64.tar.gz" > /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/build/required-node-linux-x64.tar.gz' \
```

Is `$(<.node_version.txt)` means that some text I have to come up with as the value it expects or it is used as is, part of the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you need to have a file named `.node_version.txt`. In that file should be version number of node that you want. For example: `v4.6.0` or `latest`. To see valid version strings go to https://nodejs.org/dist/

What happens is that this construct `$(<.node_version.txt)` is replaced with the contents of the file.

This line

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/$(<.node_version.txt)/node-$(<.node_version.txt)-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

becomes

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.6.0/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The construct `$(<filename)` is a special variant of a [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst). It is practically equivalent to `$(cat filename)`.